# Is there a nonnormal operator with spectrum strictly continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space.

**Definition** : An operator $A \in B(H)$ is **normal** if $AA^{*} = A^{*}A$.

**Definition** : The **spectrum** $\sigma(A)$ of $A \in B(H)$, is the set of all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $A - \lambda I$ is not bijective.
It [decomposes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_of_spectrum_%28functional_analysis%29) as follows:
 - *Point spectrum*: $\sigma_{p}(A) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C} : A - \lambda I \text{ not injective}   \}$
 - *Continuous spectrum*: $\sigma_{c}(A) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C} : A - \lambda I \ \text{ injective with a dense nonclosed range}   \}$
 - *Residual spectrum*: $\sigma_{r}(A) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C} : A - \lambda I \ \text{ injective with a nondense range}   \}$

**Examples**:

- Let $S$ be the **bilateral shift** defined on $H = l^{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ by $S.e_{n} = e_{n+1} $.
  Its spectrum is *strictly continuous* :   $\sigma(S) = \sigma_{c}(S) = \mathbb{S}^{1}$.
  It's also a unitary operator ($SS^{*} = S^{*}S = I$), so a fortiori a *normal* operator.
- Let $T$ be the **unilateral shift** defined on $H = l^{2}(\mathbb{N})$ by $T.e_{n} = e_{n+1} $.
  Its spectrum is not *strictly continuous* because $0 \in \sigma_{r}(T)$.
  It's a *nonnormal* operator because $[T^{*},T].e_{0} = e_{0}$.

> Is there a *nonnormal* operator with spectrum *strictly continuous* ?

**Bonus questions** : Can we exclude the compact operators ? How classify these operators ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets try the Volterra operator $(Vf)(t)=\int_0^tf(x)dx$ on $H=L^2[0,1].$ It is quasinilpotent (i.e. spectral radius is 0) so $\sigma(V)=\{0\}.$ Its range contains the set $\{f\in C^1[0,1]\mid f(0)=0\}$ which is dense. (To see this, note that $B=\{\sin\pi kx,\ k\in\mathbb N\}$ is an orthogonal base in $L^2[0,1].$) It means that $0$ belongs to continuous spectrum.

Comment: The set $\{f \in C^1[0,1]: f(0) = 0\}$ is still dense in $L^2[0,1]$, even the continuous compactly supported functions are dense.

Comment: **Ok, you are right !** Here is a more *conventional* approach: let $1$, $s_{n} = sin(2\pi nx)$ and $c_{n} = cos(2\pi nx)$ (with $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$) be an orthonormal basis of $H = L^{2}[0,1]$. Then $V.c_{n} = s_{n}/2\pi n$, $V.s_{n} = (1-c_{n})/2\pi n$ and $V.1 = x= 1/2 + \sum s_{n}/2\pi n$. Now $2V.(1-c_{1}-...-c_{r}) \to 1$. So $1 \in \overline{Im(V)}$, and finally $V$ is dense range.