# Is there an irreducible, noncompact commuting, nonnormal operator, with spectrum strictly continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space.

**Definition**: The **commutant** $\mathcal{S}'$ of a subset $\mathcal{S} \subset B(H)$ is $ \{A \in B(H) : AB=BA \ , \ \forall B \in \mathcal{S}  \} $.

**Definitions** : An operator $A \in B(H)$ is :

- **Irreducible** ([Halmos 1968](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/michigan-mathematical-journal/volume-15/issue-2/Irreducible-operators/10.1307/mmj/1028999975.full)) if its commutant $\{ A\}'$ does not contain projections other than $0$ and $I$ ($A \ne A_{1} \oplus A_{2}$, $A$ generates $B(H)$ as von Neumann algebra : $\{A,A^{*}\}''=B(H)$).
- **Nonnormal** if $\{ A\}'$ does not contain $A^{*}$  (i.e. $AA^{*} \ne A^{*}A$).
- **Noncompact commuting** if $\{ A\}'$ does not contain a compact operator.

**Definition** : The **spectrum** $\sigma(A)$ of $A \in B(H)$ is  $\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C} : A - \lambda I \text{ not bijective} \}$.
It [decomposes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_of_spectrum_(functional_analysis)) as follows:

- *Point spectrum*: $\sigma_{p}(A) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C} : A - \lambda I \text{ not injective}   \}$
- *Continuous spectrum*: $\sigma_{c}(A) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C} : A - \lambda I \ \text{injective, dense nonclosed range}   \}$
- *Residual spectrum*: $\sigma_{r}(A) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C} : A - \lambda I \ \text{ injective, nondense range}   \}$

The spectrum of $A$ is **strictly continuous** if $\sigma(A) = \sigma_{c}(A)$.

**Examples**:

- Let $S$ be the **bilateral shift** defined on $H = l^{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ by $S.e_{n} = e_{n+1} $.
  Its spectrum is *strictly continuous* :   $\sigma(S) = \sigma_{c}(S) = \mathbb{S}^{1}$.
  It's also a unitary operator ($SS^{*} = S^{*}S = I$), so a fortiori a *normal* operator.
  It is *noncompact commuting* and *reducible*.
- Let $T$ be the **unilateral shift** defined on $H = l^{2}(\mathbb{N})$ by $T.e_{n} = e_{n+1} $.
  Its spectrum is not *strictly continuous* because $0 \in \sigma_{r}(T)$.
  It's a *nonnormal* operator because $[T^{*},T].e_{0} = e_{0}$.
  It is *noncompact commuting* and *irreducible*.
- Let $V$ the **[Volterra operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra_operator)** defined on $H= L^{2}[0,1]$ by $(V.f)(t)=\int_0^tf(x)dx$.
  Its spectrum is *strictly continuous* $\sigma(V) = \sigma_{c}(V) = \{ 0\}$.
  It is *compact*, *irreducible* and *nonnormal* (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446466/is-there-a-nonnormal-operator-with-spectrum-strictly-continuous/)).
- Let $p$ be a non-constant polynomial (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447278/does-the-nontrivial-commutants-of-the-volterra-operator-admit-a-strictly-continu/)).
  Then $p(V)$ is *nonnormal*, *compact commuting* and *irreducible*.
  Its spectrum is *strictly continuous* $\sigma(p(V)) = \sigma_{c}(p(V)) = \{ p(0)\}$.
  It's *compact commuting*, *nonnormal* and *irreducible*.
- Let $S \oplus V$ defined on $l^{2}(\mathbb{Z}) \oplus L^{2}[0,1]$.
  It is *reducible*, *compact commuting*, *nonnormal* and with spectrum *strictly continuous*.

*If you find a mistake, thank you let me know in comment.*

> **The main question**: Is there an irreducible, noncompact commuting and nonnormal operator, with spectrum strictly continuous ?

**Bonus questions** : How classify these operators ?

Comment: [Cross-posted on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/q/137183/35324).

Comment: Hi Julien, I did not know that I'm *"supposed to let people know when you ask the same question on both site"*, thank you for this information. I hesitated between the two. I have posted it on MO first, and then on MSE. Where do you think is best for it ?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has an answer on mathoverflow, by Ollie Margetts [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137183/is-there-an-irreducible-noncompact-commuting-nonnormal-operator-with-spectrum/137522#137522), by using a weight shift.